# Detener proceso de bucle si la suma de cifras de un número es 4 o 6

Tags: java

Diseñé un programa que genere números aleatorios en el intervalo de 10 a 99
hasta obtener un número cuya suma de sus cifras sea igual a 4 ó 6. Muestre los números conforme se vayan generando y muestre al final:

- La cantidad de números generados.
- El mayor número generado.
- El menor número generado.

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que cuando en el numero aleatorio su suma de cifras salga 4 ó 6 el bucle se detenga y me muestre el mayor y menor numero que salieron de los números aleatorios.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int x, max = 10, min = 99;
for (int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {
    x = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 100.0);
    if (x >= 10) {
        txtS.append(x + "\n");
        if (x > max) {
            max = x;
        }
        if (x < min) {
            min = x;
        }
    }
}

txtnmenor.setText(min + "");
txtnmayor.setText(max + "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

    int aux,
        max=0, 
        min=0,
        segundo = 0, 
        primero = 0,
        n_aleatorio = 0,
        total = 0;    

    for (int i=10;i<=99;i++){
       n_aleatorio = (int)(rnd.nextDouble()*100.0);
       aux = n_aleatorio;

       //Obtenemos el segundo y el primer digito y lo almacenamos en las variables respectibas
       segundo = aux%10;
       aux = n_aleatorio / 10;
       primero = aux%10;

       aux = segundo + primero;
       if(aux == 4 || aux == 6){
           System.out.println(n_aleatorio);
           total++;
           if(n_aleatorio > max){
               max = n_aleatorio;
           }
           if(n_aleatorio < min){
               min = n_aleatorio;
           }
       }           
    }
    System.out.println("Se encontraron un total de  : " + total + " numeros" );  
    System.out.println("El mayor fue : " + max );
    System.out.println("El menor fue : " + min );
```

Comment: Basicamente lo que hace es separar el numero random en dos digitos, y de ahi los suma, si es igual a 4 o 6 los muestra, y luego pregunta si es menor que el minimo y si es mayor que el maximo, en cualqueir de los casos los acumula en sus respectivas variables

Comment: Hola luciano! gracias por tu respuesta. No es necesario eliminar una respuesta si no es del todo correcta. puedes utilizar el boton [edit] para modificarla. De paso, si no lo hiciste, mira [answer] y tambien [tour]!! Gracias por tu aporte y bienvenido!

Comment: Gracias gbianchi! :D la verdad vengo usando el foro hace mucho tiempo y queria comenzar a hacer aportes tambien como retribucion soy nuevito jaja saludos!

Comment: Genial!! mira los enlaces que te pase.. y cuando tengas 20 de reputación podrás utilizar el chat por si tienes mas dudas. no dudes de utilizar meta también para aquellas cosas que no entiendas!.

Comment: perfecto! muchisimas gracias por el aporte

Comment: de paso, podrias explicar que hace tu codigo a grandes rasgos? para que quede como referencia sobre todo para gente que no logre entenderlo. Siempre es bueno ademas de poner codigo, explicar porque se hizo de tal manera. Las respuestas con solo codigos no son muy bien vistas en general.

Comment: y por favor, deja una sola de las respuestas, la que consideres valida.

Answer (score 0):

Para generar los números aleatorios entre 10 y 99 (inclusivo), se puede utilizar:

```
10 + rnd.nextInt(90)
```

ya que `rnd.nextInt(90)` genera números aleatorios entre `0` y `89` (inclusivo). Por lo tanto al sumarle `10`, se obtendrán números aleatorios entre `10` y `99`.

En la instrucción se indica que se deben generar números aleatorios hasta que la suma de sus dígitos sea igual a 4 ó 6. Para esto se puede utilizar un lazo `do while` que se siga ejecutando mientras la suma del primer y segundo dígito **no** sean 4 ni 6.

Finalmente, para mostrar los valores mínimos y máximos, una opción consiste en almacenar todos los números aleatorios generados, para al final obtener el máximo y el mínimo de la lista.

El código completo se muestra a continuación:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<Integer> generatedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

int randomNumber;
int firstDigit;
int secondDigit;

do {
    int offset = 10;
    randomNumber = offset + rnd.nextInt(90);
    generatedNumbers.add(randomNumber);
    firstDigit = randomNumber / 10;
    secondDigit = randomNumber % 10;
    System.out.println(randomNumber);

} while (!(firstDigit + secondDigit == 4) && !(firstDigit + secondDigit == 6));

System.out.println("El número cuya suma es 4 o 6 es: " + randomNumber);
txtnmenor.setText(generatedNumbers.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get() + "");
txtnmayor.setText(generatedNumbers.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get() + "");
```